# vue-i18n use more than one word to translate

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

Maybe the title isn't to clear so let me explain a little bit.
I am using **vue-i18n** with Laravel and succesfully generated translation files too.
But in my translation file I used more that one word to translate. a snap of my messages
`messages:{
"Your email"="Your email",
"Email"=>"Email"
}`
Same with other language like thai language.
Inside of vue template when I use

> {{ $t('messages.Email')}}

Translation works but when i use

> {{ $t('messages.Your email')}}

It shows ***messages.Your email***
Can anyone help me to use two or more word translation??
N.B: this works in Laravel blade though

> {{ trans('messages.Your email') }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access those properties with the usual bracket syntax.

Example in plain JS:

```
const object = { 'my key': 'ABC' }

object.my key //Syntax error
object['my key'] //ABC
```

In your case with vue-i18n:

```
{{ $t("messages['Your email']")}}
```